# How to get week ending date using current week?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to get the week ending date using the current week. My problem is when the week ending date is not Friday. For ex. for the month of January 2023, the week ending date for week 5 is 31 which is Tuesday and my current code is returning Feb. 3 which is the Friday of that week.

This is the code that I've tried so far.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime weekEndingDate = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek).AddDays(5);
```

What I need is when the week ending date is fall in Tuesday, It will return Tuesday.

Comment: I am a little confused. You say "using the current week" but then proceed to talk as if you would write a general method like : "For ex. for the month of January 2023" what exactly is it? what are your input parameters ?

Comment: The parameter is the current week, I'm just assuming that when I'm in week 5 of January 2023 I'm getting Feb. 3, Instead of January 31. My current code is working, for ex. today Dec 6, my code returning Dec 9. Which is correct.

Comment: Do I understand you right, that the "end of week" is either the next Friday or end of month? `"29 Jan 2023 -> 31 Jan 2023"` (end of month), but `"17 Jan 2023 -> 20 Jan 2023"` (next Friday)?

Comment: Current Friday (Ending date of the current week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force.

```
using System;

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

var eow = GetEndOfWeek(dt);

Console.WriteLine(eow.ToString("D"));

dt = new DateTime(2022, 12, 31); // new years eve - on a Saturday

eow = GetEndOfWeek(dt);
Console.WriteLine(eow.ToString("D"));

DateTime GetEndOfWeek(DateTime date, DayOfWeek endOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday)
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek == endOfWeek) return date;

    int month = date.Month;

    while (date.Month == month && date.DayOfWeek != endOfWeek)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    if (month != date.Month) date = date.AddDays(-1);

    return date;
}
```